# db2 query based on groupings for calculated columns

Tags: sql, db2

I have a query that is working as far as returning base results but I'm having an issue trying to figure out how to select other columns/variables based on different groupings.

The base of the query is:

```
SELECT
 EmpID,
 managerID,
 Group,
 quant as sales,
from products p
where active_date > CURRENT_DATE - 50 days;
```

The issue is, these records are for 50 days but I want to select 3 new calculations as columns that are based on conditions within the last 25 days.

Say I return currently :

```
empId  |  managerID  |  group  |  sales
=======================================
123          1            A        4
321          1            B        2
516          1            C        8
345          2            D        4
839          2            E        7
849          2            F        2
192          3            G        9
221          4            H        3
```

So I would want to create a sum of sales based on a group by `empID` (sum of `sales`, group by `empID`), a group by `managerID`, and then total (but I would like to base the grouping off of only records in the last 25 days here)

An idea of my expected output (assuming all of the previous 50 day records were also in last 25 days):

```
empId  |  managerID  |  group  |  sales  | salesEmpID  |  salesMngID  |  SalesTotal
====================================================================================
123          1            A        4           4             14             39
321          1            A        2           2             14             39
516          1            A        8           8             14             39
345          2            A        4           4             13             39
839          2            A        7           7             13             39
849          2            A        2           2             13             39
192          3            A        9           9              9             39
221          4            A        3           3              3             39
```

So for product group A, this gives me each employees sales but also for that sales manager and then total sales, all for product group A

How can I get something like that and also make sure the sum of quantity is based on last 25 days even though the query is last 50 days?

Comment: In addition to showing us your current and expected output, you also should show sample input table data.  I can't seem to back out what you want to do here based on your description alone.

Comment: I'll see what I can come up with @TimBiegeleisen. I may have confused the issue but I'm basically trying to perform three new sub selects/subqueries based on a different date and a sum of quantity grouping first by empID, then mangerID and then all

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not really sure how to properly show a sample input table here, do you just mean my table definition?

Comment: Most people answering SQL questions on this site think it terms of a starting point, your input table data, and some ending point, i.e. what the expected result set is.  If we can't see this, it becomes much harder to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that should work if your RDBMS does not support window functions.

It works by creating a series of joins to compute the subtotals for each groups (employee, manager, total). See [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vaUFtHUyimyTxgHTAB7JT3/0) (I don't know about a DB2 fiddle so I used MySQL5.7, but as far as concerns this should work on DB2) :

```
SELECT 
    t.empID,
    t.managerID,
    t.groupID,
    t.sales,
    temp.sales salesEmpID,
    tmng.sales salesMngID,
    tall.sales salesTotal
FROM 
    mytable t
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT empID, SUM(sales) sales 
        FROM mytable 
        WHERE active_date > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 25 DAY 
        GROUP BY empID
    ) temp ON temp.empID = t.empID
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT managerID, SUM(sales) sales 
        FROM mytable 
        WHERE active_date > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 25 DAY 
        GROUP BY managerID
    ) tmng ON tmng.managerID = t.managerID
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(sales) sales 
        FROM mytable 
        WHERE active_date > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 25 DAY
    ) tall
WHERE t.active_date > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 50 DAY;
```

```
| empID | managerID | groupID | sales | salesEmpID | salesMngID | salesTotal |
| ----- | --------- | ------- | ----- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 123   | 1         | A       | 4     | 4          | 14         | 39         |
| 321   | 1         | B       | 2     | 2          | 14         | 39         |
| 516   | 1         | C       | 8     | 8          | 14         | 39         |
| 345   | 2         | D       | 4     | 4          | 13         | 39         |
| 839   | 2         | E       | 7     | 7          | 13         | 39         |
| 849   | 2         | F       | 2     | 2          | 13         | 39         |
| 192   | 3         | G       | 9     | 9          | 9          | 39         |
| 221   | 4         | H       | 3     | 3          | 3          | 39         |
```

Comment: I'm about to test this, and it looks like you may be a life saver! Thanks, I'll let you know shortly

Comment: I think there's a small error and part of it was on my part. I later edited the question so that the group ID for all records was A. It seems to be giving me a ton of duplicate records at the moment

Comment: Wait, I may have fixed it by changing the cross join to an inner and grouping there with additional ON clauses

Answer (score 1):

As you looking for conditional window functions?

```
select EmpID, managerID, Group, quant as sales,
       sum(case when active_date > current_date - 25 days then quant else 0 end) over (partition by empId) as emp_25,
       sum(case when active_date > current_date - 25 days then quant else 0 end) over (partition by managerId) as manager_25,
       sum(case when active_date > current_date - 25 days then quant else 0 end) over (partition by group) as group_25
from products p
where active_date > CURRENT_DATE - 50 days;
```

Comment: I think this makes sense logically but for some reason it's telling me Token ( was not valid. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO.

Comment: I ran the example in a syntax checker too and it seems to throw an error but not specifically what error

Comment: It looks like it's an issue with wanting to user over and partition for some reason

Comment: @Whisou138 : maybe caused by the column named `group`, which is a SQL keyword... You could try `p.group` instead.

Comment: I tried that as well but still get an error. Is it based on db2 version at all?

Comment: It's IBM Db2 7.1 by the way

Comment: @GMB sorry I meant to tag you in that comment. That doesn't fix it. Couldn't I achieve what I want by doing a join on a subselect as well though?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, is there maybe an alternative for what you're doing?

Comment: @Whisou138 . . . Your syntax error may be because `GROUP` is a reserved word.  Don't use reserved words for column or table names.

Comment: I resolved that error though, and it just wouldn't allow partition. I used GMB's answer above to  get a little closer but it's now omitting records. I'm hoping to get it done with subqueries though